# Show records in db by categories and count the status with total

Tags: mysql

I want to show records in db by categories and count the status,

assumed I have these records in database,

agent_tbl

```
    =========================
   | directors || status    |
    =========================
   |     AAA   || Suspended |
   |     BBB   || Deleted   |
   |     CCC   || Active    |
   |     AAA   || Deleted   |
```

This is the result I want to acquire:

```
Directors | Active | Suspended | Deleted |
------------------------------------------
AAA       |    0   |      1    |    1    |
------------------------------------------
BBB       |    0   |      0    |    1    |
------------------------------------------
CCC       |    1   |      0    |    0    |
------------------------------------------
Total          1          1         2    |
------------------------------------------
```

here is my query

```
SELECT director,COUNT(*)  
FROM agent_tbl        
GROUP BY director;
```

Comment: You might want to start accepting answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--For each director
select directors, 
count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else null end) as 'Active',
count(case when status = 'Suspended' then 1 else null end) as 'Suspended',
count(case when status = 'Deleted' then 1 else null end) as 'Deleted'
from agent_tbl
group by directors
union
--Hard code for the total row
select 'Total',
count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else null end) as 'Active',
count(case when status = 'Suspended' then 1 else null end) as 'Suspended',
count(case when status = 'Deleted' then 1 else null end) as 'Deleted'
from agent_tbl
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44757/4).

Comment: Do you understand how accepting works? There are other questions where you have also added the same comment to express appreciation, but not accepted the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: hi @shree.pat18 sorry Im beginner, what do i need to do? wheres the accept button?

Comment: Pls check the steps given in the second link. And remember to do it for every question where you have got helpful answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Directors,
       SUM(status = 'Active') AS Active,
       SUM(status = 'Suspended') AS Suspended,
       SUM(status = 'Deleted') AS Deleted
FROM agent_tbl
GROUP BY Directors
```